# Regex everything after SMC-777-

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

i am really struggeling with a Regex-Extract in Data Studio.

I want to extract every entry that comes AFTER "SMC-777-"

My data looks like this:

```
SMC-777-test1
SMC-743-test2sdf
SMC-721-test2wfsd
SMC-777-test91919
```

Comment: `SMC-777-([a-z0-9]+)`? Or `(?<=SMC-777-)[a-z0-9]+` if it supports Lookbehinds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract all characters after `SMC-777-`, the [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below does the trick, where `Field` represents the respective field name:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field,"SMC-777-(.*)")
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/dacd2f15-a3f3-44ff-aee1-91493ca8766f) and GIF to elaborate:

[image]